Insert multiple images with caption in block in the beamer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
% Tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{coord} = [coordinate, on grid, node distance=6mm and 25mm, fill=white]

\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,calc,shapes,arrows,positioning,patterns}

\tikzset{decision/.style={diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text
badly centered, inner sep=0pt}}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=8em, text
centered, rounded corners,
 minimum width=3.5cm}}
\tikzset{line/.style={draw, -latex}}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/,optimize command away=\includepdf,figure name=output]

% New Commands
\newcommand{\method}[1]{{\rm \textsf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mini}{\mathop{\mbox{minimize}}}
\newcommand{\amin}{\mathop{\mbox{argmin}}}
\newcommand{\st}{\mbox{subject to}}
%\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\mbox{\rm{(\ref{#1})}}}    % References with ()
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}           % Real  numbers
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb Z}           % Integer  numbers
\newcommand{\B}{\mathbb B}           % Binary  numbers
\newcommand{\set}[1]{{\rm \mathcal{#1}}}
\newcommand{\pctext}[2]{\text{\parbox{#1}{\centering #2}}}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathclap{\text{\tiny def}}}{=}}}
\newcommand{\ita}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand{\pp}[1]{\textsf{{\color{blue}{PP note:} #1.}}\marginpar{\color{blue}{\textbf{PP}}}} 
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{{\rm \texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\rm \textsl{#1}}}
\newcommand{\mino}[1]{{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont{#1}}}

\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{title}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{(\alph{enumi})}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[framed]
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg = black, bg = red!30}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg = red!60}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg = black, bg =red!30}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg = white, bg =red}

\newtcolorbox{myblock}[1]{
    colback=white,
    colbacktitle=red!30,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=red!50,
    title=#1
}

%% TABLE
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=authoryear,backend=bibtex,useprefix=true]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
\addbibresource{bibs/ml.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\color{violet}\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkcolorbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd{\mkcolorbibparens}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \footnotesize\color{violet}
  \blx@blxinit
  \blx@setsfcodes
  \bibopenparen#1\bibcloseparen
  \endgroup}
\makeatother


%
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[Research Presentation]{Research Presentation} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page
\subtitle{A Review on Past Researches}



\author[Shresth Somya]{Shresth Somya}
\institute[IIT Delhi]{Indian Institute of Technology, Delhi
\\Department of Mechanical Engineering \\
\href{mailto:me1201056@iitd.ac.in}{me1201056@iitd.ac.in}
}
\titlegraphic{
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.20]{logo}
    \hspace{.5cm}
}
\date[\today]{\today}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Possible Models}

\begin{columns}[T]

\column{0.3\textwidth-0.3\columnsep}

\begin{myblock}{Classification Models}
    \begin{minipage}[c][]{\linewidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}        
        \caption{\tiny ANN Model}  
    \end{figure}
    \vspace{-1.5}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
        \caption{\tiny CNN Model}  
    \end{figure}
    \end{minipage}

\end{myblock}

\column{0.7\textwidth-0.7\columnsep}

\begin{myblock}{Sequential Models}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.3\textwidth-0.3\columnsep}
        \vspace{-2}
        \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1.5\textwidth]{fexample-image-c}
        \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
        \caption{\tiny Transformer Model}  
        \end{figure}
        \column{0.7\textwidth-0.7\columnsep}
        % \vspace{.1em}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-d}
        \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
        \caption{\tiny LSTM Model}
        % \vspace{.25em}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-e}
        \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
        \caption{\tiny RNN Model}  
        \end{figure}
    \end{columns}
    

\end{myblock}

\end{columns}
    
\end{frame}

\end{document} 

For the slide below, I have written the code above.

I want to make both blocks the same size and reduce the distance between the boundary and the image. I have mentioned the space in the image below.


Welcome! Unfortunately, nobody can compile your code snippet but you. Can you edit your question to make your code compilable? This means adding a minimal preamble, the document environment and replacing your own images with standard ones. example-image-a, example-image-duck, cow, mill etc. are all fair game. figures/SER/ann.png, unfortunately, is not. If the size really matters, use the example-image-* ones with width and height set to match your images. (The mill would also work; the cow not so much.)

Did you test your document as it is in the question?
